# Need to fetch description of selected item from local storage using the selected 'id'

Tags: angular

In my slist.component.html i am showing list of names with a button, when i click on the button it gives me the **id,description** of that selected name using this function below which is written in **slist.component.ts** , the value is in variable **selectdescription**.

How can i access this **selectdescription** on my another component **edits.component.ts**

```
 go_to_editsection(i){
    var selectsection = this.array_no1[i]['id'];
    var selectdescription = this.array_no1[i]['description'];
    console.log(selectsection);
    console.log(selectdescription);
    this.router.navigate(['/editsection/'+selectsection])
  }
```

> Please note: I am calling the id in the url also, if user hits the button from slist.component.ts, then the edits.component.html/:id is called.

This is how i am receiving the id in edits.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.section = {id: this.route.snapshot.params['id']};
    console.log(this.section.id);
}
```

Can i find description from locally stored data using the id ? Which method shall i use ? Like bringing values from other component or fetching value from the id i have already bought ?

My data which is stored locally is being fetched in `array_no1` using the code below in **edits.component.ts** -

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.section = {id: this.route.snapshot.params['id']};
    console.log(this.section.id);
 var keys = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function(key) {
  return /^section\d+$/.test(key);
});

var dataArray = keys.map(function(key) {
 return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
});

for(var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
    var array_no = dataArray[i];
}
 this.array_no1 = dataArray;
  }
```

Please guide, also attaching the 2 screenshots for better understanding:
[image]

Once the button is clicked -
[image]

Comment: You can't access the variable because its scope is the function. 

However, you can declare a global variable that you export, and set its value in the function.

Comment: th=ried this - `let obj2 = this.array_no1.find(obj2 => obj2.id === 682);` , if you see i have declared `public array_no1` on top but it is also giving same error, what is that i am doing wrong

Comment: In your **slist.component.ts** file, add `export myValue: any = null;` and in your function, do `myValue = selectdescription;`. Now, you can import your **slist.component.ts** in every file and access your exported variable.

Comment: yes i commented on the wrong page, so i just deleted...so sorry for that

Comment: Did the same. So did I answered your question?

Comment: where do i declare this `export myValue: any = null;` inside class or outside both showing error when i am creating it

Comment: You declare this as a first liner, meaning outside of everything. And try `export var myValue:any = null;`